# put state on redux's store if it's async state

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have confusion what state should be put on reducer/store in redux after writing react redux app for a while. Like toggle state, dropdown state, those 'minimal' shouldn't be in the store right? because that belong's to the UI's, it won't be used or shared between multiple components.

So I assume put the states that is async into store of redux, am I correct?

Comment: Can you explain the purpose of your question?

Comment: @mickaelw to understand whether I'm doing it right using redux

Comment: https://redux.js.org/docs/faq/OrganizingState.html

Answer (score 1):

You can store whatever you want you'll use in different places in your app, fetched data or not.

For example you probably want to keep and use in different components in your app some settings your user configured, or to save form data before sending...

Comment: I can but for what purpose? for example a toggle state, it doesn't belong to elsewhere but the toggle state itself in a page.

Comment: If it's a state that have an impact on other components you should dispatch it, it's also easier to persist the state of your entire app and to avoid unexpected behaviours between components that use the same state